# Because in the middle of a question

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, question-mark

Do I put a question mark after the following sentence?

> Do you know where it is because I cannot find it?

I guess it is quite simple but I get really confused when the 'because' is there. To me the question doesn't seem like after the 'because'. Should it be two sentences?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be 2 sentences, unless you omit because: "Do you know where it is? I cannot find it." The sentence as it stands is still a question - adding "because ..." does not stop it being a question: it just explains why you are asking the question.

Comment: "No, I know where it is because I saw it there before. Your inability to find it is unrelated." In other words, yes, your question should be split in two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write it like this.

> Do you know where it is? Because I cannot find it.

Question mark after *is*, because that is the end of the question. Then you're making a statement. Two separate sentences in the example you used.

Comment: I agree that it should be two sentences because it's two statements but I disagree that it should be written quite like this. The problem is that with this sequence is that the second sentence is fractured. As uninterrupted dialogue, the second sentence should be "I ask because I can not find it." so that [because](http://edl.byu.edu/webstersearchresults.php?wq=because&x=0&y=0) has something to give a cause. If you do otherwise, you are technically suggesting the inquired person knows where it is since you don't. It would be fine as a response to "Why do you ask?" between sentences though.